# Access video feed from webcam with iPhone 15 over USB C

Tags: iphone, ios, usb, video, webcam

Now that the iPhone has USB C, is there a way to access the video feed from a usb webcam connected to the iPhone?

I know the iPad supports it out of the box in apps like face time but according to some videos online the iPhone does not.

Are there any APIs that would make it possible to show the video feed of a connected webcam in an iOS app?

I’d like to not have to use any hardware in between.

I know there are devices like the [Flir one](https://www.flir.de/products/flir-one-gen-3?vertical=condition%20monitoring&segment=solutions) thermal imaging camera which can be connected and using app the video feed could be seen. That already worked with lighting, so now with usb c it should be even easier?
Also, there must be certain APIs that Flir is using in their app to access the device.

Comment: Same question, right now I think it's not supported on iOS, otherwise all those apps would have been updated from iPadOS support to iOS/iPadOS support:
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dongled/id6465788521
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hdmi-monitor-orion/id6459355072
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/genki-studio/id6466343285 Do you know how does work the Flir One? An option is that it works fed by USB-C power supply from iPhone 15 and streaming images through a direct WiFi connection.

Comment: @VincentBounce Flir One requires Lightning, the USB-C models won't work. And they are powered by an internal battery, so one way or the other the Lightning port is used to transfer video data.